# Switch Statements not working

Tags: php, html, switch-statement

I'm trying to use the switch statements but it's not working. My problem is for example i input LazyBoy in the textbox, that should echo LazyBoy else echo another string.

```
<?php

  $classmap = $_POST['classmap'];

  switch ($classmap) {
    case "LazyBoy":
        echo "You're Lazy!";
        break;
    case "GrayHounds":
        echo "You're Gray!";
        break;
  }

?>
```

Here is the form -

```
<form action="checkout.php" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name ="classmap" value="<?php include('db.php');
    $origin = $_POST['origin'];
    $class = $_POST['class'];
    $daten = $_POST['daten'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM route WHERE route LIKE '%$origin%' AND type LIKE '%$class%' AND date LIKE '%$daten%' ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $row['type'];
    }   ?>">

  </form>
```

Comment: Is your textbox definitely named 'classmap'?

Comment: please post `var_dump($_POST)` output

Comment: Have you tried any debugging here?  What are you POSTing to this page?  What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Yes Boann, yes i will have 3 conditions thats why i will use switch statement.

Comment: I have a textbox name "classmap" then i will get its value and have this conditions. if classmap = "1" echo 1 else echo 2.

Comment: You can try to echo your variable $classmap directly, so you will see what's in it, and continue searching from there.  Also, beware of case sensitive text.

Comment: The problem is your form's value. You cannot put all of that PHP code in there. By posting an incomplete question you have caused a lot of people to guess what your problem is. Make sure to *always* post all of the relevant information for any question you have.

Comment: **What**! What is in your database table column _routers.type_ Does it all belong in that single hidden field??

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Talk us through the logic by editing your post and explaining what you expect the input and output to be.

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Im trying to echo the values from the textbox, and it's right. when i try to compare if this textbox is equals to ="LazyBoy" or "GrayHounds" its not working.

Comment: again, post `var_dump($_POST)` output in `checkout.php`

Comment: array(4) { ["route"]=> string(2) "23" ["qty"]=> string(160) " " ["date"]=> string(12) " 0000-00-00" ["classmap"]=> string(16) " GrayHounds" }

Comment: what are you passing in value of class map. what is that db.php ?

Comment: "GrayHounds" should be 10 characters long but your string is 16 characters long. It's obviously full of space.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to post values to define  the classmap index.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="classmap" value="LazyBoy"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php


  $classmap = (isset($_POST['classmap']) ? $_POST['classmap'] : null);


  switch ($classmap) {
    case "LazyBoy":
        echo "You're Lazy!";
        break;
    case "GrayHounds":
        echo "You're Gray!";
        break;
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @Jay Blanchart  - you are right. thanks. i just said to try this because  I tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the post variable is set and/or add a default case :

```
if(isset($_POST['classmap'])) {
     $classmap = $_POST['classmap'];

     switch ($classmap) {
        case "LazyBoy":
            echo "Your Lazy!";
            break;
        case "GrayHounds":
            echo "Your Gray!";
            break;
        default:
            echo "Something";
            break;
     }
}
else {
     echo "Something";
}
```

Comment: I always echo "Something"

Comment: If it always echo "Something", then the value is not "LazyBoy" or "GrayHounds".  Display the content of your variable and you will know for sure what it is:  echo $classmap

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you post to the right script.
Try to put default statement to debug.

```
$classmap = $_POST['classmap'];

switch ($classmap) {
   case "LazyBoy":
       echo "You're Lazy!";
       break;
   case "GrayHounds":
       echo "You're Gray!";
       break;
   default:
       echo "does not match with previous cases";
}
```

Comment: How do you guys format the posted code? My post is in 1 string and no color. :(

Comment: it always echo "does not match with previous cases"

Comment: then you can try to echo out the $classmap

Answer (score -1):

Your Code is correct.
I guess there is a Problem with the $_POST.

Try to verify it.

```
$classmap = "LazyBoy";
```

Comment: Yes its LazyBoy or GrayHounds.